# SMT 2011. Coefficient of x

Tags: polynomials

**Problem**

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial with degree 2011 such that $P(1) = 0, P(2) = 1, P(4) = 2,..., P(2^{2011}) = 2011.$ Compute the coefficient of the $x^1$ term in $P(x)$

**Solution**

Let $Q(x)=P(2x)-P(x)$

$Q(x)-1$ has $1,2,4,...,2^{2010}$ as roots

$Q(0)=P(0)-P(0)=0$, so $$Q(0)-1=-1=A(-1)(-2)...(-2^{2010})=-2^{\frac{2010*2011}{2}}A$$

Finally, note that the coefficient of $x$ is same for $P$ and $Q-1$, so it equals $$A(-2^0)(-2^1)...(-2^{2010})((-2^0)+(-2^1)+...+(-2^{2010}))=\frac{A*2^{1005*2011}(2^{2011}-1)}{2^{2010}}=2-\frac{1}{2^{2010}}$$

I have understood most of the question except for $A(-2^0)(-2^1)...(-2^{2010})((-2^0)+(-2^1)+...+(-2^{2010}))=\frac{A*2^{1005*2011}(2^{2011}-1)}{2^{2010}}=2-\frac{1}{2^{2010}}$

How and why is the coefficient equal to the expression, why is $(-2^{2010})((-2^0)+(-2^1)+\dots+(-2^{2010}))$ here and where did the same expression come from?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: $A=2^{2011}-1$.